# Relationship between $L_1$ and $L_2$ distances of two Gaussian Mixture models

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

Given two Gaussian mixture models with
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &=\sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_{k} \mathcal{N}\left(x \mid \mu_{k}, \sigma_{k}\right), \\
g(x) &=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_{i} \mathcal{N}\left(x \mid \mu_{i}, \sigma_{i}\right),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I want to compute their $L_1$ distance,
\begin{equation}
\delta_{1}(f,g) = \int_{x} |f(x) - g(x)|.
\end{equation}
However, the $L_1$ distance cannot be computed directly, and I use the squared $L_2$ distance instead, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\delta_{2}(f,g) = \int_{x} (f(x) - g(x))^2.
\end{equation}
The closed-form expression of $L_2$ distance is available (c.f. [Distance between two Gaussian mixtures to evaluate cluster solutions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71879/distance-between-two-gaussian-mixtures-to-evaluate-cluster-solutions)), but I want to know: does there exist any relationship between $L_1$ distance and $L_2$ distance in this case?

Comment: What kind of relationship are you hoping for? an upper and lower bound should be attainable, but the constants would depend (plausibly, I guess) on the "diameter" $\max_{i,k} |\mu_k-\mu_i|$ as well as on the ratio $\frac{\min_j \sigma_j}{\max_j\sigma_j}$ (hopefully not on $K,N$).

Comment: @leomonsaingeon, thanks for the comment. Actually, I want to find an inequality relation between $L_1$ and $L_2$ distance, and how could I attain these upper and lower bounds?

Comment: Inside a big ball you can use Young/Cauchy-Schwarz to bound $L^2\lesssim L^1$. And outside of a big ball your mixtures behave essentially as the single Gaussian with the smallest $\sigma$, so you can compare $L^2$ and $L^1$ explicitly. Then you should take care of the details, optimizing the radius of the ball, taking into account the shifts $\mu_i=\mu_j$ etc, but I guess this should work

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Thanks for the hint.